# Continuity Correction with replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

An urn contains 2 white and 8 red marbles. A marble is drawn from the urn 100 times in succession with replacement. What is the probability of drawing more than 75 red marbles?

My attempt:

$n=100, p=0.8, q=1-p=.2$

$\mu=np=80, \sigma^2=16, \sigma=4$

$Z=(X-\mu)/\sigma$

$P_B(X\geq75)=P_N(75.5<x<100.5)$

$=P_N((75.5-80)/4)<x<((100.5-80)/4)$

$=P_N(-1.125<z<5.125)$

$=.5000-(-3708)$

$=.8708$

Can someone please tell me if this working is correct?

Comment: Numerically OK. It should be $\Pr(X\gt 75)$. Some of the notation is wrong. We want to write $\Pr(Z\gt (75.5-80)/4)$.